Intermittent Connection Issues with Sequelize Migrations in Docker Compose Setup
I am using Docker Compose to set up my application, which consists of three services: a MySQL database, a backend API, and a Vue.js frontend. My backend uses Sequelize for database migrations.
However, I am facing an issue where Sequelize migrations only work intermittently. I occasionally get the error:
ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.3:3306

This suggests that the backend service is unable to connect to the MySQL database service. The error happens when running the following command:
docker-compose up -d --build && docker-compose exec backend npx sequelize-cli db:migrate

Here is my current docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
      MYSQL_USER: user1
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password1
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - DB_HOST=mysql
      - DB_USER=user1
      - DB_PASS=password1
      - DB_NAME=mydatabase
      - JWT_SECRET_KEY=yourSuperSecretKey
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  vue-app:
    build:
      context: ../frontend
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    volumes:
      - ../frontend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true

volumes:
  db-data:

config.json:
{
  "development": {
    "username": "user1",
    "password": "password1",
    "database": "mydatabase",
    "host": "mysql",
    "dialect": "mysql"  
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "user1",
    "password": "password1",
    "database": "test_database",
    "host": "mysql",
    "dialect": "mysql" 
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "user1",
    "password": "password1",
    "database": "production_database",
    "host": "mysql",
    "dialect": "mysql" 
  }
}


The error message occurs when the backend container attempts to run the migrations. It seems like the MySQL container isn't ready when the backend tries to connect to it. The issue is intermittent — sometimes the migration runs without any problem, but other times it fails with the ECONNREFUSED error.
My questions:
What is the best way to ensure the backend service waits until MySQL is fully ready before running the migrations in a Docker Compose setup or fix ECONNREFUSED?

The linked questions discuss several approaches to it; possibly the most straightforward approach is to add a health check to the MySQL container, and then use the extended form of depends_on: that waits for this health check to pass.
